# Capture stills from avi on Windows

Tags: capture, avi

I need to capture stills from avi files. I also need to know avi file duration. The Platform is Windows, the language is C++ (with Qt library). I don't know much about DirectShow or Qt Phonon and I have no time to learn any of them. So I'm looking for ready made solutions. Maybe there is some open source project where I can find some sources for inspiration? Or maybe there is some free dll which can do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is http://ffmpeg.org/. There are windows C++ sources.

Answer (score 0):

The avi file duration can usually be easily calculated from information in the header. Getting a still will require decoding the video stream using ffmpeg or similar, as Cipi suggests.